# Convert string into Enum

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

[image]

I am working on WCF service and want to return preference key as enum rather than string.

How to make enum of preferencekey column which is string type in best optimized way?

Comment: I cant change db structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rohit,

The value of `preferenceKey` could not easily be converted to an enum as you would expect.  The strings could be parsed using Enum.Parse() method however the enum names must be different than what you have in the database.  The problems are

1. Your string starts with a number
2. Your string contains the `-` characters

Now that being said you could design a different approach to your naming convetion of an enum as an example (I dont like this example personally but might work).

First define a new attribute called `EnumName` this attribute will be used to decorate your enums with the name that you expect from the database. Such as

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class EnumNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly string name;

    public EnumNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
}
```

The next step will be to define your enums (what I dont like is the names)

```
public enum Preferences
{
    [EnumName("6E-SF-TYPE")]
    SIX_E_SF_TYPE = 0,
    [EnumName("6E-SF-VALUE")]
    SIX_E_SF_VALUE = 1
}
```

Simple enough, we have our enum with each item decorated with the `EnumName` attribute. The next step will be to create a method to parse the enum based on the string from the database.

```
public static class EnumNameParser
{
    public static Preferences ParseString(string enumString)
    {
        var members = typeof(Preferences).GetMembers()
                                            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumNameAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                                            .Select(x =>
                                                new
                                                {
                                                    Member = x,
                                                    Attribute = x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumNameAttribute), false)[0] as EnumNameAttribute
                                                });

        foreach(var item in members)
        {
            if (item.Attribute.Name.Equals(enumString))
                return (Preferences)Enum.Parse(typeof(Preferences), item.Member.Name);
        }

        throw new Exception("Enum member " + enumString + " was not found.");
    }
}
```

This method simply takes an input stream, evaluates all the `EnumNameAttributes` and returns the first match (or exception if not found).

Then this can be called such as.

```
string enumString = "6E-SF-TYPE";
var e = EnumNameParser.ParseString(enumString);
```

Now if you want to take the enum and get the name for the database you can extend your helper method with

```
public static string GetEnumName(this Preferences preferences)
{
    var memInfo = typeof(Preferences).GetMember(preferences.ToString());
    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumNameAttribute), false);
        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            return ((EnumNameAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
    }
    throw new Exception("No enum name attribute defined");

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) Method:

```
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), enumString);
```

I found the [code snippet](http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/string-zu-enum/1012).

Comment: @wudzik: Thx for formatting. It's very early in Germany, I'm still sleepy.

Comment: I know something about that ;]

Comment: Also, there is a third parameter (a bool). Passing in 'true' means that the parsing is case-insensitive, which can be extremely useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I really would recommend storing the numerical values rather than the text values in the database.  If you want the text values in the database too then add a table for it.  Regardless, the Enum.Parse and .TryParse methods will convert a String and the .ToObject method will convert either text or numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make enum of preferencekey column which is string type in best optimized way

Well i am afraid you cannot use your preference key as enum for 2 reasons.

1. your preference key is starting with integer values making it an in-valid identifier.
2. it also contains **-** which is not allowed either.

However, if you are able to convert your preference key to some valid identifiers then you can do this.

i would recomment using [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for parsing because

> TryParse(String, Boolean, TEnum) is identical to the Parse(Type, String, Boolean) method, except that instead of throwing an exception, it returns false if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need for exception handling when parsing the string representation of an enumeration value.

Something like this

```
string testingString = "Test1";
SomeEnum result;
if (Enum.TryParse(testingString, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

or if case sensitivity doesn't matter to you. Then you can use the overload like this

```
if (Enum.TryParse(testingString,true, out result))    
   Console.WriteLine("Success");
```

where SomeEnum is

```
public enum SomeEnum
    {
        Test1 = 1,
        Test2 = 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simples way to do this would be:

1) create an enum representing all possible preference key values, but add a 'invalid' with value -1.

```
enum PreferenceKey
{
    INVALID = -1,
    SIX_E_SF_TYPE = 0,
    SIX_E_SF_VALUE = 1,
    ...
}
```

2) create a list of strings containing the string representations of all preference key values **in the same order as the enum**.

```
private List<string> strings = new List<string> {"6E-SF-TYPE", "6E-SF-VALUE", ...};
```

3) Lookup the column value in the list of strings and cast the position to the enum.
If the column value cannot be found in the list of strings, IndexOf will return -1, which is the 'invalid' value.

```
PreferenceKey key = (PreferenceKey) strings.IndexOf(preferenceKeyColumnValue);
```